# Authentication failure for FTP server

Tags: server, ftp, authentication

I followed [this link](http://cviorel.easyblog.ro/2009/03/05/how-to-setup-vsftpd-ftp-on-ubuntu-linux/) to install ftp server.

And also added ftp user(**ftpuser**) and also added ftp password(**1234567**).

But when I am using this password in any wordpress site or any ftp software such as FileZilla it is showing **530 Login incorrect[image]**

**vsftpd file**

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
write_enable=YES
local_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
ftpd_banner=Welcome to blah FTP service.
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back up the config file before making a change;

```
sudo cp /etc/vsftpd.conf /etc/vsftpd.conf.back
```

and then edit vsftpd.conf (with vi or nano)

```
nano /etc/vsftpd.conf
```

Then make the following change

```
pam_service_name=ftp
```

Save your change and restart the ftp server (if you use nano hit CTRL+O & enter to save then CTRL+X to exit)

```
sudo service vsftpd restart
```